# Keep specific columns of a sheet - delete all others

Tags: vba, excel

My code below works well but somehow it takes long time to do such a small operation. And is also doing more than I need. I am asking for some help to improve it.

I just need to keep the columns "nameA" "nameB and "nameC" of sheet "incidents_data". Delete all others columns.

I would like also to get ride of this parte:'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "x". Dont need it.

```
Sub keep_specific_columns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    Dim columnHeading As String

    For currentColumn = Worksheets("Incidents_data").UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = Worksheets("Incidents_data").UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "nameA", "nameB", "nameC"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete if the cell doesn't contain "x"
                If InStr(1, _
                    Worksheets("Incidents_data").UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value, _
                   "DLP", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

                     Worksheets("Incidents_data").Columns(currentColumn).Delete

                End If
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub keep_specific_columns()
    Dim currentColumn As Integer, _
        columnHeading As String, _
        ColzToDelete As String, _
        CounT As Integer, _
        Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Worksheets("Incidents_data")

With Ws
    For currentColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.CounT To 1 Step -1
        columnHeading = .Cells(1, currentColumn).Value
        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "nameA", "nameB", "nameC"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                'Delete store the columns to delete them at the end
                ColzToDelete = ColzToDelete & "," & _
                                Col_Letter(currentColumn) & ":" & Col_Letter(currentColumn)
                CounT = CounT + 1
        End Select
        If CounT <> 10 Then
        Else
            'Delete when you have 10 columns
            .Range(Right(ColzToDelete, Len(ColzToDelete) - 1)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            ColzToDelete = vbNullString
            CounT = 0
        End If
    Next currentColumn
    If ColzToDelete <> vbNullString Then .Range(Right(ColzToDelete, Len(ColzToDelete) - 1)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With

End Sub
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Col_Letter = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work if i want to keep more than 10 columns?

Comment: Yes, you just have to set new name in your select! ;)

Comment: got an error: Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch - highlighting : Col_Letter(currentColumn)

Comment: `Dim currentColumn As Long` will fix this, the function is expecting a long, my bad for missing it! ;)

Comment: thnaks. It works! Just one commnet, is it normal that takes around 20 seconds to remove 10 columns? tahnks.

Comment: Hopelessly, It might... `.Delete` isn't really efficient. You only deleted 10 columns? Because the code will delete batches of 10 columns and finaly delete the remaining columns after the end of the loop.

Comment: Thats right, my dataset can have between 8 and 13 columns. Not more.

Comment: Ok... So it is freakingly ineffecient... :/

Comment: Thats why I wanted to improve my code- any suggestion?

Comment: take a look at this, but you'll need to hide all the columns that doesn't interest you and then delete them using the code, but I'm not sure the time efficiency difference will be huge (I hope so for you!)